# Is it possible to figure out which "Path"(PointCollection) is clicked on within a PolyLine?

Tags: c#, geometry, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf

I am using ArcGIS WPF's `Polyline` to plot several lines (`PointCollection`s). Adding a Path(`PointCollection`) looks something like this.

```
PointCollection collection = new PointCollection();
PolyLine myLine = new PolyLine();

collection.Add(firstMapPoint);
collection.Add(secondMapPoint);

myLine.Paths.Add(collection);
```

`PolyLine` is a Geometry in which I can set to a `Graphic` and plot on a map. Once that `Graphic` is clicked it of course is clicking the entire graphic. I am visually showing several Paths(`PointCollection`s). Is it possible to figure out which Path is being clicked on from the user?

**Note**

I have a solution now where I just have 1 `PointCollection` per `PolyLine`. So I am adding one `PolyLine`/`Graphic` for each line. I would rather not do this if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have one Path per Polyline you can do something like this:

```
private void map1_MouseClick(object sender, Map.MouseEventArgs e)
{
            if (map1.Layers["MyGraphicsLayer"] is GraphicsLayer)
            {
                GraphicsLayer glayer = (GraphicsLayer)map1.Layers["MyGraphicsLayer"];
                IEnumerable<Graphic> graphics = glayer.FindGraphicsInHostCoordinates(map1.MapToScreen(e.MapPoint));

                foreach (var graphic in graphics)
                {
                //Do stuff
                }
             }
}
```

But if you want to use several Paths per Polyline I guess you have to look at catching the polyline that gets clicked and split that polyline into several polylines and use the [GeometryService](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.GeometryService.html) to do some relation operations on these.